# iOS Bluetooth delegate connect function not being called

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I'm trying to listen to all Bluetooth connect/disconnect events.  Even though the delegate's `centralManagerDidUpdateState` function is called, nothing happens when I connect or disconnect Bluetooth devices.

I'm confused as to what's going wrong.  I initialize the Central Manager/delegate like this:

```
var btDelegate: CBCentralManagerDelegate = BluetoothDelegate()
var btManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: btDelegate, queue: nil)
```

BluetoothDelegate is defined like so:

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

class BluetoothDelegate : NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!) {
        println("connect") //this line is not called
    }
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, error: NSError!) {
        println("disconnect") //this line is not called
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
        println("state update") //this line is called
    }
}
```

*Note: I can continuously receive more state update events such as when I toggle Bluetooth, even though connect and disconnect are not called.*

Comment: I've not familiarized myself yet with how Swift behaves when you have a reference to a base class but assign a derived class object to it - hence if btDelegate should be of type BluttoothDelegate instead of CBCentralManagerDelegate or not I can't say. But if you get no other answers it is something to try.

Comment: I just tried using BluetoothDelegate instead of CBCentralManagerDelegate, but the behavior was not different.  It was worth a try though.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's a field in a class we use; I don't think it ever goes out of scope.  I didn't know that was a weak reference though- that's good to know.

Comment: Where are you connecting to peripherals? How do you know that they're connecting?

Comment: We paired it in the Bluetooth settings pane.  An important thing to note is that we're trying to react to connection events themselves in-general, not scan/communicate.

Comment: They're not `nil`, because we can continue to receive state update events even though connect and disconnect don't occur.  It turns out that iOS has a separate concept of being connected "locally" to your app, and connect/disconnect are only called upon local connections.  I'm not sure how to listen for bluetooth pairing itself, though, which is the goal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your code it looks like you haven't started scanning for peripherals. Once you have confirmed that your central is in powered on state from `centralManagerDidUpdateState` method you should start scanning for your peripherals.

(The bluetooth devices you connected from bluetooth settings panel are irrelevant. *You can't have access to them.* (as far as I know) Incase you want to scan and find out your device on your own below code will help)

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
  switch (central.state) {
  case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff:
    break
  case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn:
    startScan() // start scanning once the bluetooth is On
    break
  default:
    break
  }
}
```

And your startScan method will be  (You can provide service UUID, use `nil` if you want all )

```
func startScan(){
  if let central = btManager {
    central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    println("started Scanning")
  }
}
```

After that whenever you discover a peripheral `didDiscoverPeripheral` method will be called first.

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {
  println(peripheral)
  // btManager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
}
```

From there you collect the peripheral and then invoke `connectPeripheral` method of `CBCentralManager`. If the connection is successful `didConnectPeripheral` method will be called.

You should go through [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#) for complete details